# PreparedStatement is not executed and RowMapper is not called

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

For a simple login access check I am using jdbcTemplate with the following DAO method :-

```
    @Autowired
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public List<User> hasAccess (String user, String pass) {
            return jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
                @Override
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SHB_USERS WHERE USER=? AND PASS=?");
                    ps.setString(1, user);
                    ps.setString(2, pass);
                    return ps;
                }
            }, new RowMapper<User>() {
                @Override
                public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rownum) throws SQLException {
                    String user = resultSet.getString("USER");
                    String pass = resultSet.getString("PASS");
                    User userObj = new User(user, pass);
                    System.out.println(userObj.toString());
                    return userObj;
                }
            });
        }
```

But somehow `mapRow` is not called. When I use direct String instead of `PreparedStatement` for example `select * from shb_users where rownum <2` it works.
I am new to Spring boot and cannot find out the mistake.

Comment: Did you try to run this with debug logs and show-sql property as true to see if the prepared statement executes correctly?

Comment: @shishir kumar Haven't tried that But I changed one of the `setString` index to 3 and faced invalid index error

Answer (score 0):

If the result set from your query is empty, your row mapper won't be called.

Can you confirm there is a matching username and password in the `SHB_USERS` table?

Comment: Thanks, record exixsts, but user being a reserved word in oracle was the issue

Comment: I'm glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have identified the problem in your code, I will still go ahead and mention it for other users who end up on this page while finding the reason behind no action from `mapRow(...)`.

```
@Nullable
T mapRow(ResultSet rs,
                   int rowNum)
            throws SQLException
```

As per the Spring's official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html#mapRow-java.sql.ResultSet-int-),

```
This method should not call next() on the ResultSet; it is only supposed to map values of the current row.
```

This interprets that at any given execution of this method, the `cursor` within the parameter `ResultSet rs` is at the single row denoted by the `rowNum` parameter. If the `resultset` has no rows at the passed `rowNum`, then there will not be any execution of this method.